# Sklearn performs better than Pyspark

Tags: scikit-learn, classification

I have created 2 scripts for training a simple classification decision tree with cross-validation.
The problem is that sklearn is performing better in time and accuracy than a spark.
I have the exact same configuration so I don't really get how Spark gets 0.43 acc but sklearn gets 0.89 acc.

Also, I have 4 nodes, 16Go Ram.

The first one with pySpark :

```
# PySpark validation croisée distribuée
from pyspark.ml.feature import StandardScaler
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

sc.stop()
sc = SparkContext("local[*]", "Decision Tree Classifier")
spark = SparkSession(sc)

df = spark.read.csv("creditcard.csv", inferSchema=True, header=True).toDF("Time", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20", "V21", "V22", "V23", "V24", "V25", "V26", "V27", "V28", "Amount", "Class")
df = df.drop("Time")

start = time.time()

#on assemble les features dans un vecteur
df = VectorAssembler(inputCols=df.drop("Class").columns ,outputCol="features").transform(df)

# split comme avec sklearn
split = int(0.7*df.count())-1 
train = df.head(split)
test = df.tail(df.count()-split)

training = spark.createDataFrame(data=train, schema = df.columns)
testing = spark.createDataFrame(data=test, schema = df.columns)

tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol="Class", featuresCol="features") 
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tree])  

# on tune le parametre maxDepth, j'ai essayé avec un seul paramètre car sklearn etait plus rapide que spark 
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(tree.maxDepth , [10,30]).addGrid(tree.minInstancesPerNode, [1, 3]).build()                                

crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline,
                          estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                          evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(labelCol='Class'),
                          numFolds=3)

cvModel = crossval.fit(training) #entrainement avec validation croisée

prediction = cvModel.transform(testing)
auprc = sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score(np.array(testing.select("Class").collect()), np.array(prediction.select("prediction").collect()))
print("AUPRC : " + str(auprc)+", time_exec : "+str(time.time()-start))
```

The second one with Sklearn :

```
# Scikit learn validation croisée
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn import tree

start = time.time()

df = pd.read_csv("creditcard.csv")
df = df.drop("Time", axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df, df])

#split comme avec spark
split = int(0.7*len(df))-1
train = df.iloc[:split,:]
test = df.iloc[split:,:]

train_x = train.copy().drop("Class", axis=1)
train_y = train["Class"].copy()
test_x = test.copy().drop("Class", axis=1)
test_y = test["Class"].copy()

clf = GridSearchCV(tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(), {'max_depth':[10, 30], 'min_samples_leaf':[1,3]}, n_jobs=3)

clf.fit(train_x, train_y)
pred = clf.predict(test_x)
auprc = sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score(test_y, pred)
print("AUPRC : " + str(auprc)+", time_exec : "+str(time.time()-start))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will ask on CrossValidated. There is a time column but I remove it to not use it as time series. I did this split to have the exact same data for each algorithm.

Comment: Also, why did people downvoted my question ? Is it because this forum is only about code error ?

Comment: I think so. Stack Overflow is really for non-working code, when the actual output does not match the desired output. Also, you should try to make sure that your examples are absolutely as small as necessary, and that people can run them (e.g. with fake data).